# After installing MySQL cannot run basic commands in Mac terminal

Tags: mysql, terminal, jupyter-notebook, command, ls

I installed MySQL yesterday and today cd, ls commands cannot be found in terminal. When I type in `echo $PATH` in terminal, I got `/usr/local/mysql/bin:`

I also tried to open Jupyter notebook from Anaconda-Navigator and below is what I got.

```
/anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command: line 1: dirname: command not found
/anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command: line 3: /jupyter-notebook: No such file or directory
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing MySQL via Docker. 
You can install docker and expose the port 3306 with the following commands.

- Install Docker
- To pull latest docker image

```
docker pull mysql:latest
```

To run mysql docker image

```
docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_DATABASE=<db-name> -e MYSQL_USER=<username> -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=<user-password> -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=<root-user> -p 3306:3306 -v mysql:/var/lib/mysql -d mysql:latest
```

After running the above command you can access `mysql` at `localhost:3306`